# I created a new group & new user. I then added the user to the group. How can I change to that user?

Tags: su, useradd

I created a new group called `tomcat` and then created a new user called `tomcat` that I added to group `tomcat`:

```
sudo groupadd tomcat
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
```

`whoami` returns `ubuntu`

I want to change user from `ubuntu` to `tomcat` so I tried `su tomcat`.

But its asking me for password. I never set a password.

How can I change user to `tomcat`?

Answer (score 1):

In a typical setup a user without a password will be unable to authenticate, and can't switch to is with just `su tomcat`, but in your case you are assigning `/bin/false` as the default `shell` for that user, so you have to use `-s /bin/bash` to allowing change to `tomcat` user.

So if you create a new user you can switch to it using `sudo su <username>`, but, in your case it won't let you switch to it because of `-s /bin/false`, and when you do that that mean this user is attempt to used to run daemons.

In regular case use `sudo passwd <username>` to create a new password for that specific user.

Comment: I see. Yeah, the tomcat user/group is created to run tomcat as a systemd service. I thought I can become `tomcat` user when I need to edit files since only the user has read/write permissions. I didn't think I have to set a password using `sudo passwd <username>`. I think I asked the wrong question.

Comment: @kimbaudi to become a `tomcat` user change the `-s /bin/false` to `-s /bin/bash`.
then use `sudo su tomcat` without changing the password

Comment: I already created user `tomcat`. How can I change `-s /bin/false` to `-s /bin/bash`? When I run `sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat`, I get response `useradd: user 'tomcat' already exists`

Comment: @kimbaudi change it from `/etc/passwd`, file replace the `/bin/false` with `/bin/bash`

Comment: I just ended up removing user `sudo deluser tomcat` and then adding user again `sudo useradd -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat`. I didn't have to do `-s /bin/bash` because that is the default. I can change user as `tomcat` with `sudo su tomcat`, but when I try to access a file to edit, I get password prompt. `sudo nano conf/tomcat-users.xml` returns `please enter a password`. I still need to `sudo passwd tomcat` to set the password. Your solution helps me change to `tomcat` user, but its not what I'm looking for. I think I asked the wrong question. You can update your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @kimbaudi in my answer i didn't say that you can do what ever you want in your user without asking you for a password, i said if you want to switch to user without being asking for a password use `sudo su username`, and your question was to switch without a password

Comment: Yes you're right. That's why if you update your answer to say changing `-s /bin/bash` allows changing user as `tomcat` with `sudo su tomcat`, then I will accept.

Comment: @kimbaudi i did, i will remove unnecessary comments

Answer (score 1):

You have set up your user so that it can't login. OK, this is a **good** habit to prevent a daemon user such as `tomcat`, `apache`, `mysal`,... from logging in.

Now, your only solution is to switch to that user as root:

```
sudo su -l -s /bin/bash tomcat
```

Here, as root (`sudo`), you are doing a login as user tomcat (`su -l tomcat`). The `-s /bin/<shell>` option is necessary since the default shell would be `/bin/false`, which would end your session immediately.